# Create column using a sequence of numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such

```
 Anger      Sad     Happy     Disgust     Neutral    Scared
 0.06754  0.6766    0.4343    0.7732       0.5563     0.76433
 0.54434   0.9865   0.6654    0.3334       0.4322     0.54453
 ...
 0.5633   0.67655  0.5444     0.3278       0.9834     0.88569
```

I would like to create a new column that marks the first 5 rows as 1, the next 5 rows as 2, the next 5 rows 3 and then the next 3 rows as 4, and repeat the same pattern till the end of the dataset. How can I achieve this?

I tried looking into arange but failed in the implementation

An example output would be the new column Tperiod

```
Tperiod
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 3
 3
 3
 3
 3
 4
 4
 4
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Comment: Why is it having ones again at the end of the column?

Comment: I used that just to show the sequence

Comment: I am not that familiar with pandas (yet). But you might want to check pandas `rolling` or `expanding`: [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be as such

```
pattern = [1] * 5 + [2] * 5 + [3] * 5 + [4] * 3 
no_patterns = len(df)//len(pattern)
remaining = len(df) - (len(pattern) * no_patterns)
new_values = pattern * no_patterns + pattern[:remaining]
df['new_column'] = new_values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
gr=[5,5,5,3]
mp={n: next(x+1 for x in range(len(gr)) if sum(gr[:x+1])>n) for n in range(sum(gr))}

df['Tperiod']=range(len(df))
df['Tperiod']=(df['Tperiod']%sum(gr)).map(mp)
```

Where `gr` indicates your groups size (that's your input), and `mp` is just to utilize it properly with `pandas`.